# Bootstrap 3.3.6 collapsed navbar dropdown list not aligning properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I added a media query at 1180px wide for horizontal viewing on tablets so that the navigation menu items don't wrap to a 2nd line, but instead displays the toggle button. However when clicking the toggle where it displays the main menu, that menu has several dropdown sub-menus. At this width, when clicking on a menu item to see a sub-menu,those choices are displaying over toward the far right instead of immediately under the main menu choice - [See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJzcj.png). Yet it acts just fine under 767px wide. Since I am not sure how menu items get aligned to begin with when showing the mobile menu, I am not sure what is causing this or how to correct it. Thanks in advance.